# A variadic template method to accept a given number of doubles?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic

```
template <unsigned int N> class myclass
{
public:
    template <typename... Args> void mymethod(Args... args)
    {
       // Do interesting stuff
    } 
};
```

I want `mymethod` to be called only with exactly N doubles. Is that possible? That is, say that I have:

```
myclass <3> x;
x.mymethod(3., 4., 5.); // This works
x.mymethod('q', 1., 7.); // This doesn't work
x.mymethod(1., 2.); // This doesn't work
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the number of arguments constraint you can easily check if `sizeof...(Args) == N` but for checking if all the arguments are doubles you need to build a recursive type trait that checks `std::is_same` for each of the arguments.

```
template<typename...>
struct are_same : std::true_type 
{};

template<typename T>
struct are_same<T> : std::true_type
{};

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Types>
struct are_same<T, U, Types...> :
    std::integral_constant<bool, (std::is_same<T, U>::value && are_same<T, Types...>::value)>
{};
```

Notice `are_same` is first declared and then **specialized**.

Then just implement the constraint in your method return type using `std::enable_if` by taking advantage of [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

```
template <unsigned int N> class myclass
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    typename std::enable_if<(are_same<double, Args...>::value && sizeof...(Args) == N), void>::type
    /* void */ mymethod(Args... args)
    {
        // Do interesting stuff
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try something like following :

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class...>
struct all_same : std::true_type
{};

template<class T, class U, class... TT>
struct all_same<T, U, TT...>
    : std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<T,U>{} && all_same<T, TT...>{}>
{};


template <unsigned int N> class myclass
{
    public:
    template <typename... Args>
     typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) == N, void >::type mymethod(Args... args)
    {
        static_assert(all_same<double, Args...>{}, 
                      "Not all args as Double");
    }
};
```

[*`<Demo>`*](http://rextester.com/DPWGK4951)

Comment: Close but your use of `enable_if` is somewhat broken and results in UB here (per the warning in your demo); you should have it yield `void` on success.